# ¿Como obtener path de un archivo mediante la URI en android?

Tags: android

Para seleccionar un archivo abro un file chooser mediante un Intent:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Después en el onActivityResult obtengo la uri del archivo:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                Log.d("TAG", "File Uri: " + uri.toString());

                try {
                    path = getPath(this, uri);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Tengo un método getPath pero al parecer no funciona, el código es:

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    }
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Por las pruebas que he hecho la URI sí se obtiene correctamente, sin embargo el path siempre es null.

Hasta ahora lo único que me ha funcionado es obtener el path para imágenes, pero me gustaría que el código funcione para cualquier tipo de archivo o al menos para documentos como (pdf, docx, etc), a continuación adjunto el código para imágenes.

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

//handling the image chooser activity result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando encontré este código que me ha funcionado para obtener el path de cualquier archivo.

```
/**
 * Created by Aki on 1/7/2017.
 */

public class PathUtil {
    /*
     * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        // deal with different Uris.
        if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```